# Passing object data via tabs - object assigned in tab at index 0- iOS

Tags: ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I have a block of code to pass information between tabs, from my Home tab to Account. In the destination tab the object however is null. `personAcc` and `personHome` are `Person` objects.

```
AccountController *myVc = (AccountController*) [[(UINavigationController*)[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
myVc.personAcc = self.personHome;
NSLog(@"mvc %@",myVc.personAcc.firstName);
```

I am sure this is a correct way to pass information between tabs. It successfully logs the first name, however when I log in `AccountController` it is null.

```
self.personAcc = [[Person alloc]init];
NSLog(@"mvc %@",self.personAcc.firstName);
```

Any ideas where the error may lie?

Im still finding my feet with iOS so please excuse any silly mistakes I may have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit my previous post. Try the code below.
Just make sure the delegate of the TabBarController is set.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController Class]]) {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
        AccountController *myVc = nav.viewControllers[0];
        myVc.personAcc = self.personHome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I have just removed the allocation but it is still null

Comment: Thanks for the code, I got it firing however I put a log statement inside in the conditional statement but its not firting. `AccountController` is the name of the class I want to go to

Comment: Try to NSLog(@"%@",[viewController class]); to see what's going on. If everything was set up correctly on the storyboard that code should work.

Comment: its prints out `UINavigationController`

Comment: i edited again the code above. The code assumes that the first view controller of your navigationController is the AccountController.